# Running my JApplet on html in my computer

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I work on Eclipse Luna on my windows 7, the java version insatlled on the computer itself is up to date.
I build some simple JApplet to see how it runs on an html page in my computer. I mean not through
'run as applet' in eclipse, rather on a real html page.
But I can not run it due to the restriction - "Application blocked by java security". How can I see it? do I must get certificate for just simple trial? 
If yes, how to do it with eclipse? Is it a short procedure? Can I see the applet runs without it?
Thanks in advance, Liron

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I use explorer 11 and also chrome

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have enabled Java for your web browsers? [Here](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml) are instructions for Internet Explorer:

> - Click Tools and then Internet Options
> - Select the Security tab, and select the Custom Level button
> - Scroll down to Scripting of Java applets
> - Make sure the Enable radio button is checked
> - Click OK to save your preference

Comment: It still not working. The enable radio was checked there already. I still get 'Application Blocked' : 'Your security settings have blocked a local application from running'

Comment: @user3344394 Then you may be out of luck and you may have to get and apply a (perhaps self-signed) certificate: see [here](http://java.com/en/download/help/appsecuritydialogs.xml).

Comment: In the old version of java, In 'Java control panel', I put the slider there in the security tab to 'low' (or simialr), and then I could run it. Now they change this to 2 option: high and very high, and now it can be set to 'low' any more.

Comment: @user3344394 I'd try a self-signed certificate next.